# When a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For what values of real $t$ $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=txy\}$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I presume you mean a sub-vector-space? What are the properties of a subspace? There should be a list in your book of things to check.

Comment: @Arthur a subspace is the same as a "sub-vector-space"

Comment: @WillFisher Well, there are other kinds of interpretations of "space" that could apply to $\Bbb R^2$. Most commonly, metric or topological. They also give rise to "subspaces", but with different demands.

Comment: I know that the set will be a vector subspace if it's closed under addition and multiplication by scalar, but don't know how to find the values of t

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
For $t=0, \pm 2$ the set is $\{(0,0)\}, y =\pm x$ respectively. All of which are subspaces. Now ask your self what happens when $t \neq 0, \pm 2$.

**Additional comments**

Suppose $t \neq 0, \pm 2$. Let $(a,b)$ and $(p,q)$ be points in the set. Then 
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2 & = tab\\
p^2+q^2 & = tpq\\
\end{align*}
For the set to be a subspace, you need closure under addition. So you need to check if $(a+p, b+q)$ is in this set. In other words, will
$$(a+p)^2+(b+q)^2 = t(a+p)(b+q)????$$

Comment: Do I have to show that the equation doesn't hold for $t\neq0,-2,2$? If so, how?

Comment: @TomaszTarka What do you mean "the equation doesn't hold"? For any real number $t$ you get an equation in $x$ and $y$. That equation describes a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. You have to show that that subspace is _not_ a subspace.

Comment: I mean that is not true for every $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I stated it wrong, I mean that I need to show for $x, y$ in the set that their sum is not a solution for that equation for $t\neq-2,0,2$. Is that the right approach?

Comment: @TomaszTarka I have added some comments to help you better understand.